# VIM: How to set default color on search based syntax highlighting

Tags: vim, colors

Currently my /etc/vimrc file is set to the following: (

```
if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
syntax on
set hlsearch
endif

filetype plugin on

 if &term=="xterm"
 set t_Co=8
 set t_Sb=^[[4%dm
 set t_Sf=^[[3%dm
 endif
```

My problem is that whenever I am in VIM and search for a string when it finds it it highlights it in a bright yellow block. This not not a problem unless I try to find text that is white, then it makes it very difficult to see. I have tried changing the line:

```
set hlsearch="another_color"
```

But I get an error when trying open back up the file after saving.

```
Error detected while processing /etc/vimrc:
line   51:
E474: Invalid argument: hlsearch=light
```

In this block of code something tells me this controls background and foreground colors, but I am not sure if that pertains to the "hlsearch" option.

```
if &term=="xterm"
 set t_Co=8
 set t_Sb=^[[5%dm
 set t_Sf=^[[6%dm
endif
```

I have tried changing the 5 and 6 to different numbers and that has no effect. I still have a yellow highlight box for searched text.

So my questions are:

1) Where is this "default" yellow color coming from?

2) How do I change it to something else?

Answer (score 2):

All syntax colors, including the search highlight color, are set by changing a highlight group rather than an option.  You set these groups with the `:highlight` command.  For example I have changed search highlighting from yellow a bright turquoise:

```
:highlight Search guibg=Turquoise4
```

I have also changed the `IncSearch` color, which is the color when `'incsearch'` is set:

```
:highlight IncSearch gui=underline,bold guifg=White guibg=Red3
```

See `:help :highlight` and `:help highlight-groups`.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. In /etc/vimrc under the "syntax on" line add:

```
hi Search ctermbg=red
hi Search ctermfg=white
```

This example will give you a red block with white text while searching files with VIM. Inside VIM you can also do:

```
:highlight Search ctermfg=yellow
```

To change it on the fly.